# How do I get the value assigned to on-click in paper-button?

Tags: polymer

I need this for custom element that can decorate event handlers e.g. for showing a confirmation dialog when you click on a button. Specifically, I need to know the name of event handler to be able to remove it with `this.unlisten` and define a wrapper for it.

Answer (score 2):

There's currently no public API for this, but you could use the following code, which reaches into Polymer internals to get at the bound event listeners. **Since it uses Polymer's private API, this solution isn't guaranteed to work in future releases.**

In Polymer 1.5.0, [event listeners](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/events#event-listeners) are added to an internal property `__boundListeners`, which is a map of event names to method names. The format of the keys in this map is `"<eventName>:<methodName>"` (e.g., `"tap:_handleTap"`). So, you'd be able to find all methods that listen to a particular event by searching `__boundListeners`:

```
function getListenerMethods(target, eventName) {
  var boundListeners = this.__boundListeners || {};
  var listeners = boundListeners.get(target) || {};
  var methodNames = Object.keys(listeners).filter(function(key) {
    return key.split(':')[0] === eventName;
  }).map(function(key) {
    return key.split(':')[1];
  });
  return methodNames;
},
```

In the demo below, I used a mixin on `Polymer.Base` to add `unlistenAll()`, which allows you to use the function from your Polymer object like this:

```
this.unlistenAll(this.$.myButton, 'click');
```

Here's the demo:

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+1.5.0/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="paper-button/paper-button.html">
</head>
<body>
  <x-foo></x-foo>

  <script>
    HTMLImports.whenReady(function() {
      // Mixin
      Polymer.Base._addFeature({
        /**
        * Gets the names of all methods listening to an element's event.
        *
        * @param {Element} target Node element to retrieve method names from.
        * @param {String} eventName Name of event to look up.
        * @returns {Array} names of handler methods on `this`
        */
        getListenerMethods: function(target, eventName) {
          var boundListeners = this.__boundListeners || {};
          var listeners = boundListeners.get(target) || {};
          var methodNames = Object.keys(listeners).filter(function(key) {
            return key.split(':')[0] === eventName;
          }).map(function(key) {
            return key.split(':')[1];
          });
          return methodNames;
        },

        /**
        * Removes all listeners of a specific event from a given element.
        *
        * @param {Element} target Element to remove event listener from.
        * @param {String} eventName Name of event to stop listening to.
        */
        unlistenAll: function(target, eventName) {
          var self = this;
          this.getListenerMethods(target, eventName).forEach(function(methodName) {
            console.log('unlistening "' + eventName + ':' + methodName + '" from:', target);
            self.unlisten(target, eventName, methodName);
          });
        }
      });
    });
  </script>

  <dom-module id="x-foo">
    <template>
      <paper-button id="btn" on-click="_click">click</paper-button>
    </template>
    <script>
      HTMLImports.whenReady(function() {
        Polymer({
          is: 'x-foo',

          _click: function() {
            console.log('clicked');
          },

          ready: function() {
            this.unlistenAll(this.$.btn, 'click');
          }
        });
      });
    </script>
  </dom-module>
</body>
```

<sup>[codepen](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/rLLoyv?editors=1001)</sup>